# How to get more results returned from an API?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I am trying to use the [GeoDB Cities API](http://geodb-cities-api.wirefreethought.com/) to retrieve a list of every single city (might change this to any city larger than 10,000 or so) in the United States. Problem is, I'm only able to get 10 city objects returned to me at once. Is it possible to make multiple calls to get a complete list of every city in the US?

I plan to use this list of cities to create an autocomplete input. Would this API approach make sense for this use case? Or would it make more sense to either -

A.) Hard code a long list of every US city in my component and pass to autocomplete input.

B.) Store list of every city in a database and pull from that. I'm building my first app and haven't used databases before so am intimidated by this approach, ha.

C.) Open to suggestions.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.geoDbService.findPlaces({
      namePrefix: '',
      countryIds: ['US'],
      minPopulation: 100000,
      types: ['CITY'],
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0
    })
    .subscribe(
      (response: GeoResponse<PlaceSummary[]>) => {
        const totalCount = response.metadata.totalCount;
        const data: PlaceSummary[] = response.data;

        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: use `offset:10` to get the next 10, `offset:20` to get the 10 after that, etc - perhaps there's something in the response that tells you if there's more? check the response ... of course, once you get less than 10, you know there's no more (hint, the response metadata has a total count)

Comment: Sounds like a limit on the host, does the api doc say anything about how many records are returned if limit is set more than 10?  It looks like a paid service.